# Threads in Java. "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a timer, it makes every 0.02 seconds of action.
The actions there checking on the condition, if it is carried out - call Thread for playing music.
The problem is that while the melody is playing, this condition is again checked. In result Exception:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
- Background.java
....
 Thread eventMusic = new Thread(new EventMusic());
... check different conditions ... (every 0.02s)
 if everything is ok  -> eventMusic.start();

- EventMusic.java
package Shooter2Dv23082013;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class EventMusic implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Player p = new Player(new FileInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/nameSong.mp3").getPath()));
            p.play();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}


    }
}
```

The question is.

1. Create multiple threads? How to create threads for each condition (ie, a lot of threads, but I do not know how many of them will, after work - it will closed)
2. Frankly, it begs the observer template, if all conditions are met - notify () thread that wants to play a song, for different occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, your problem is probably in your check-function.

You could use some kind of lock to prevent a condition-check while playing music:

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();


Thread eventMusic = new Thread(new EventMusic());
lock.lock();
... check different conditions ... (every 0.02s)
if everything is ok  -> eventMusic.start();
lock.unlock();


public class EventMusic implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        lock.lock();
        Player p = new Player(new FileInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/nameSong.mp3").getPath()));
        p.play();
    } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
       lock.unlock();
    }

 }
}
```

You should place the lock somewhere so both classes can access it

Comment: i found solution , it's - using ExecutorService, i think your solution isn't worse

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough code to pin-point the problem but one of your threads have tried to modify a collection that one of your other threads is iterating over currently.

The JavaDocs for [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) say

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible. For example, it is **not** generally permissible for one thread to **modify** a Collection while another thread is **iterating** over it.

If a thread is allowed to continue iterating over a collection which is simultaneously being modified the program behaviour would become non-deterministic and it would fail at an undetermined time leading into hard to find bugs. Hence, this exception is thrown by the `Iterator` and the program is said to have *failed fast* rather than failing later. Iterators that do this are known as ***fail-fast*** iterators.